# cmd. flatten directory structure works only if not called from batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a pretty common task: copy all files from subdirectories into one directory without the directory structure. Googling found the following:

```
for /r . %f in (*.xaml) do xcopy "%~f" package /F /R /Y /I
```

Executing it from the command line works like a charm. When I put it into a script, I get the following output:

```
~f" package /F /R /Y /I was unexpected at this time.

C:\MyStuff\Test>for /r . ~f" package /F /R /Y /I
```

My guess is that while interpreting the script, everything between two `%` is interpreted as a variable name. The next guess is that I need some escaping, workaround or indirection. How can I get cmd to interpret the script correctly?

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I wasn't aware that `for` is a command in batch and that `for /?` even exists.  If you make this an answer I'll accept it. (I don't see how a question asking for the right syntax should be deleted because it's caused by a syntax error.)

Comment: @ArneMertz how else would you know how to use a command if there was no documentation on its usage? This style of help functionality is petty much how it was done on all operating systems well before any of them had a graphical user interface.

Comment: @Squashman In most languages, for is not a command, but a keyword and syntactical element. Had I been aware that it is a command, I would have used /? immediately.

Comment: @ArneMertz - The DOS/Windows style of help is `<command> /?`. Common examples include `for /?`, `if /?`, `dir /?`, `robocopy /?`, `rmdir /?`, `mklink /?`, etc...

Comment: `everything between two % is interpreted as a variable name`: correct. `I need some escaping`: correct. Well analyzed. `%` is escaped by another `%`, so it's `%%f` and `%%~f`.

Comment: @lit thanks! I knew of `<command> /?`, but not that `if`, `for` etc. are commands